# Testing for post title in 'if/else' statement returns no content

Tags: posts, content, title, the-content

I'm testing for a certain fixed post on an about page, I guessed that the best way is to test for post title (?).

Here's my code, what's going wrong?

```
<?php
if (is_page()) {
  $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title);
  $posts = get_posts ("cat=$cat&showposts=35");

  if ($posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $post):
      setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <div class="clear"></div>

<?php    if ($post->post_title('skillset')) {
            echo '<div class="content">';
                the_content('');
            echo '</div>'; 
    }
        else{
        the_content('');
        }
                endforeach;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off all, `$post` is one of the WordPress core [global variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) and as such should either not be touched or [reset](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after your `foreach` loop.

Using [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) allows you to make use of [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) such as you are doing in the above snippet with `the_title()`. It, or the loop it is used in, should however always be followed by its companion [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Also `$post` is an [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). Objects are instances of classes that contain properties and/or methods, the OOP equivalents of variables and functions.

By attempting to test for the post title in the way that you did,

> `if($post->post_title('skillset'))`

you treated `post_title` as if it was a method and could be fed the title in question as an argument as well as would return a boolean. It however is a property and as such contains a value that you can access - and that is it.

This value then needs to be [tested against](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) another value. Hence

```
if( 'skillset' === $post->post_title ) {
    // your conditional operation
}
```

would be a working test for the title.

Essentially that line is the answer to the question in your title. Since you however asked what might be wrong with your code, also the `showposts` argument has been deprecated for a while. Use `numberposts` instead.

Also let's revisit the initial point on using `$post`. If instead of the template tags you'd reference the properties directly, it would not be necessary to overwrite the global `$post`.

```
$wpse67413_posts = get_posts();

foreach( $wpse67413_posts as $wpse67413_post ) {
     echo '<h3>' . $wpse67413_post->post_title . '</h3>';
}
```

Would work just as well without touching the global. That just for the sake of completeness.

And as a side note, why would you use that many php opening and closing tags in such little space? Pretty much a rhetorical question: It just doesn't make sense.

At last, are you sure, you want to do this:

> `$cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title);`

? This only makes sense if you want to fetch posts of a category named exactly the same as the title of the page the visitor is on. Assuming the answer is positive, here's the complete correction of your above snippet:

```
global $post;

if( is_page() ) {
    $wpse67413_posts = get_posts( array(
        cat => get_cat_ID($post->post_title),
        numberposts => 35
    ));

    if( $wpse67413_posts ) {
        foreach ( $wpse67413_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata($post);

            echo '<div class="clear"></div>' .
                '<h3>' get_the_title() . '</h3>' .
                '<div class="clear"></div>';

            if( 'skillset' === $post->post_title ) {
                echo '<div class="content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>'; 
            } else {
                the_content();
            }
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to search for ID, not title! So then your if would be:

```
if ($post->ID === 123)
```

where 123 is the ID of the post you want to "filter".

Comment: And just in case you want to test for post title you would do this: `if( $post->post_title == 'my title' )`